# How to dynamically set fieldname and fieldvalue in mongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to be able to set the fieldname and fieldvalue from user input. I'm creating a website where you can place an ad. An ad could be anything so i can't have a predifined schema. All ads have common properties, such as title, price etc..
I was thinking of creating an array inside every document that has the details of that particular product. 
This is my Ad model :

```
        title: String,
        description: String,
        isActive: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false
        },
        region: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Region'
        },
        phoneNumber : String,
        dateCreated: {
          type: Date,
          default: Date.now
       },
       category: {
       type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category'
       },
       price: {
        type: Number
       },
       details:[ {
        name: String,
        value: String
  }]
```

In my create Ad endpoint i want to be able to send an array containing all the details of that particular Ad. so each element in the array will have a fieldname and fieldvalue. 
`e.g: fieldname: color, fieldvalue: black`
`fieldname: year, fieldvalue: 2015`
And in my database i want to have this result.

```
   details: [
      {color: black},
      {year: 2015}
   ]
```

Is this even possible? if so how would i do that? I'm using nodejs and mongoose.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Of course. This is possible. But Make sure Whatever dynamic fields you want to store needs to be in Schema.

```
Ex. f1: 'username', f1Value: 'xyz'
```

So here 'username' needs to declared in your Mongoose Schema. Unless you have 'data' key which is assigned as an Obj or an array. Then you can insert anything and in any format for that key. 
Then you can get values and create Add Object for that and you can add values like this.

```
dataObj = [];
dataObj[0][keyName] = keyValue;
user = new User({ 
    data: dataObj
});
user.save();
```

This is just a demo example. Don't insert dynamic records like this. Get a proper request and create a separate loop for that data.

Hope this helps.